# Link visible between certain times

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

I would like someone to help me please.

I need a link to be visible between certain times say 6pm & 1am in the evenings. Clients that are registered on my site can change the times of store opening and closing times within their admin panel and it connects to a table in a database.

The link needs to only be visible during specified times that the client decides via their control panel. Out side of these hours the link is hidden/not visible and not clickable.

So this needs to call/echo times from database table for each customer.

any help would be great.
many thanks

Mark

Comment: Your question is quite general, you might want to share what you have tried and where you are stuck.

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like...

```
// check if the date (current hour) is between two times, 
// if it is, assign the link to $link, else assign nothing to $link
$link = date('H') >= 6 && date('H') <= 20 ? '<a href="#">Link</a>' : ''; // replace hardcoded hours with vars if needed
echo $link;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
// Assuming $userMin and $userMax are the users specified times
$time = date( 'H' );
if( $time > $userMin && $time < $userMax ) {
    echo "<a href='linkUrl'>Description</a>";
}
```